# WooCommerce API : list product with filter (e.g : no virtual)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using Automattic\WooCommerce (PHP) to create an external module for my WooCommerce. I want to list all products only if it's not a virtual product.

Is it possible? How can I do that?

I already tried like these but it doesn't work

```
$params = [
    'attribute' => 'virtual',
    'attribute_term' => true
];
//or
$params = [
    'virtual' => false,
];
//or
$params = [
    'virtual' => 0,
];
$products = $services->search($table, $params);
```

Comment: Can you explain more about what doesn't work with your attempt?

Comment: Even if I search with these filter, I always get virtual product in response. They doesn't work.